# Why a get a collation conflict when adding hibernate update?

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-server-2008

Hello I am trying to add `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to work on an existing database but I get this error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation
```

I didn't have problems with this before. 
I tried to change the database collation but I don't think that is the problem. 
I already ckecked questions about this error but they weren't relationated to hibernate. I dont know if it also can be a problem with spring.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nativeSqlHelper' defined in class path resource [be/retailability/util/hibernate/hibernate.ac.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [be/retailability/util/hibernate/hibernate.ac.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: petfood.dbo.AccrualHeader
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:639)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:109)
at be.retailability.util.spring.SpringLauncher.launchApplication(SpringLauncher.java:33)
at be.retailability.util.spring.SpringLauncher.launchApplication(SpringLauncher.java:24)
at be.retailability.util.AbstractLauncher.startSpringApplicationContext(AbstractLauncher.java:359)
at net.pearlchain.erp.services.launcher.AllServicesLauncherBase.startSpringApplicationContext(AllServicesLauncherBase.java:126)
at net.pearlchain.petfood.services.launcher.AllServicesLauncher.startSpringApplicationContext(AllServicesLauncher.java:97)
at be.retailability.util.AbstractLauncher.startApplicationContextSync(AbstractLauncher.java:197)
at be.retailability.util.AbstractLauncher.start(AbstractLauncher.java:145)
at net.pearlchain.petfood.services.launcher.AllServicesLauncher.main(AllServicesLauncher.java:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [be/retailability/util/hibernate/hibernate.ac.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: petfood.dbo.AccrualHeader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: petfood.dbo.AccrualHeader
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.checkForExistingForeignKey(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:533)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetForForeignKeyInformation(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:1003)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:875)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:798)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a MSSQL database:

- initial auto-creation of db-scheme by hibernate worked fine
- scheme auto-update by hibernate failed with the error described above.

I solved it by setting the collation property of the database to Latin1_General_CI_AS.

A logic explanation would be, that during scheme creation the collation property is not relevant. But during scheme update hibernate creates some queries that depend on the collation.
Since hibernate seems to use or expect Latin1_General_CI_AS for it's queries this generates the conflict.

Comment: Yes I tried this before and I think is the correct solution. For me it didnt work cause the DB was very big and changing the collation was a nightmare.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for this to handle it from Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 0):

I try with:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EditionId') AS EditionId
GO
use master
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbaname] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
GO
use [dbaname];
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbaname] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbaname] SET MULTI_USER
GO
```